# Trying to communicate over a serial connection between RPi and Picaxe 18M2 Microcontroller?

Tags: serial, uart, serial-console

I am trying to get a serial connection between an RaspberryPi and a Picaxe 18M2 Microcontroller. I found out that I should build the following cirucit because the Rasperry and the Microcontroller have different levels.

[image: The level adjustment circuit]

So here is a picture of my attempt to build this circuit.I checked it several times but maybe I made a mistake anyway (If needed I will send more pictures):

**My attempt**
[image: Main Part]

I have the following code, that run's on the Picaxe 18M2 Microcontroller

```
main: 'high B.3 'green led
      'high B.0 'red led
       serout C.3,N4800,(10,13)  'Start a new line
       serout C.3 ,N4800,("Press a key- ") ' Send a message
       serin C.4,N4800,b1 ' Receive a character into variable b1
       serout C.3,N4800,(b1) ' Transmit character back to the screen
       if b1="a" then hot ' Is character ?a?? If yes goto hot
       goto main 'No, so loop back to start
hot:   serout C.3,N4800, (10,13,"A is the Hot Key!")
            high B.0
            pause 5000
            low B.0
            pause 5000
            high B.0
       goto main ' Loop back to start
```

I tried to connect over putty on my PC about the same serial connection I use to program the microcontroller. So i open a serial connection with putty on my COM1 Port with a baud rate of 4800. There the programm works. Not perfectly but it works and i am able to highlight a red led when i enter an "a". When I'm opening a serial connection on the Raspberry with minicom on /dev/ttyAMA0 I'm just getting back some weird charachters and it seems like i'm not able to send a charachter back to the microcontroller. I also tried baud rates of 600,1200 and 2400. I event tried it with picocom but that doesn't work either. Does anybody have an idea what I could be doing wrong?

Comment: have you disabled the serial console?

Comment: yeah i used this script: https://github.com/lurch/rpi-serial-console to do it

Answer (score 1):

Personally I'd dump 90% of that circuitry.

Assuming the PICAXE is 5V.  The Pi is 3V3.

Connect the grounds.

Connect the Pi's TX to the PIXAXE's RX (use a series resistor if you want).

Connect the PICAXE's TX to the Pi's RX using a pair of resistors to cut the PICAXE 5V to a Pi safe 3V3.

Use `stty -F /dev/ttyAMA0 x` to set the Pi's baud rate to x.

Comment: I did like you said and connected the Pi's TX to the Picaxe's RX directly.

I also changed to the Pi's baud rate to 4800 which I tought would solve my problem but it doesn't work anyway.

Comment: The code seems to be using 600 baud as well as 4800.  That might be confusing the issue, although I don't really see why.

Comment: Oh thanks i messed this up because I was trying out different baud rates. You're right that should be 4800 as well.